# Why winforms modal form losing focus and unblock UI after reconnecting to remote session

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a WinForms application where I use modal dialog forms (opened using ShowDialog()). The application is often accessed via remote desktop. However, I've noticed that when a remote desktop session is disconnected and then reconnected, the open modal dialog loses its focus and modality. Specifically, while the dialog is still visually open, it no longer blocks interaction with the main form

I've tried handling the Deactivate event in the modal dialog to call this.Activate() or similar methods to regain focus.

Comment: Make sure that 1) the dialog is displayed from the UI thread. 2) the dialog has its owner correctly set. Also consider creating a minimal reproducible example. If the problem is in your code you probably need to show what you are doing to get any help.  If there is a problem in windows or .net it sound like a fairly serious bug.

Comment: So I've checked that the dialog is displayed from the UI thread, I didn't have an owner correctly set but I've tested this scenario also and issue still occurs. I've notice that half of UI is still blocked as it should be but the ribbon in my app which is a part of Infragistics Winforms is losing his modality and it's unblocked. Also I've created minimal reproducible example with simple dialog form and after reconnecting to remote form doesn't lose his modality and focus

Comment: Then it is likely a problem with the third party control that does something weird, seek support by them.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has struggled with a similar issue with Infragistics, setting the `IsGlassSupported` property to `false` in `UltraToolbarsManager` might resolve your problem.

Here's link from Infra forum:
https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-windows-forms/119592/remote-desktop-disconnect-reconnect-tx-textcontrol-losing-all-but-plain-text/530646#530646